# is this code correct re memory management - for a basic custom class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management

do I need to add/modify anything here re memory management for a custom class?  (e.g. any "release" lines required, don't need a dealloc method?)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface TimelineItem : NSObject {
    NSDate *_startDate;
    BOOL _working;
    BOOL _coreWeekend;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *startDate;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL working;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL coreWeekend;
- (id)initWithStartDate:(NSDate*)startDate Working:(BOOL)working CoreWeekend:(BOOL)coreWeekend;
@end



#import "TimelineItem.h"
@implementation TimelineItem
@synthesize startDate = _startDate;
@synthesize working = _working;
@synthesize coreWeekend = _coreWeekend;
- (id)initWithStartDate:(NSDate*)startDate Working:(BOOL)working CoreWeekend:(BOOL)coreWeekend {
    if (self == [super init])
    {
        // Initialization
        self.startDate = startDate;
        self.working = working;
        self.coreWeekend = coreWeekend;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not.  You've `retained` the `startDate` parameter by declaring your property as `(retain)`.  This means you're responsible for `releasing` it at some point.  You can fix this by adding:

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [_startDate release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Also, you shouldn't be capitalizing "Working" and "CoreWeekend" in the init method name.  They should be "working" and "coreWeekend", respectively.

Comment: thanks Dave - I see rooijaro suggested to use "= nil" as opposed to release?  any comments here re which approach?

Comment: Does it matter if you release `_startDate` or `startDate`? Is either OK?

Comment: @nevan you can use `self.startDate = nil;` in `-dealloc`, but it's not recommended.  Likewise, since you did `@synthesize startDate=_startDate;`, you have to use `_startDate`, since that's the name of the instance variable.

Comment: what about using use "= nil" instead Dave - any comments on this?

Comment: @Greg simply doing `_startDate = nil;` would still leak the retained object.  Doing `self.startDate = nil;` would work, but has the side effect of invoking a method with potential side effects during the deallocation of the object.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement `-dealloc` and release `startDate` there. Otherwise, this appears to be fine.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [_startDate release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to release _startDate when the class is dealloced. Since you have as a property, the safest thing to do is set it to nil, and the auto-generated setter will take care of releasing it for you.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    self.startDate = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```